# Winform Custom Controls - Designer randomly stops initializing / calling constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

This is a freaking nightmare and I'm desperately needing help.  I've looked EVERYWHERE for help NOTHING has worked as a permanent fix.

I've got some custom controls I've developed; controls that extend button, user control, etc.  I have an issue that VS2010 constantly and randomly, with no rhyme or reason that I can discern, decides when I try and open the design view of a control which uses the custom control that it **(EDIT:  'it' being Windows Forms generator)** should COMPLETELY REMOVE THE LINE which calls the constructor for the custom control from the .designer.cs file, thus completely breaking my ability to view the Design View.  The application still builds and runs completely fine.

I've tested and ruled out the following as issues:

1. Public constructor - evidently having a non public (internal, etc.) constructor can cause issues like this.  I've checked 100 times - ALL the custom controls have public constructors.
2. Empty constructors - in addition to being public, it needs to be empty.
3. No calling anything that could fail in the constructor - I've reduced ALL constructors for custom controls to empty

   ```
    Name() { }
   ```

   calls.  No luck there.
4. Namespaces - evidently being in a different namespace can cause problems?  I'm in the same one, and the files are IN THE SAME PROJECT.
5. Unload project.  Close VS.  Delete .suo intellisense file.  Delete obj files.  Open VS.  Reload project.  Rebuild project.  Still no luck.

This is INSANELY frustrating.  It's to the point I'm ready to throw out using custom controls and SKIN EVERY CONTROL INDIVIDUALLY BY HAND TO AVOID IT.  Does ANYONE have ANY knowledge of what causes this?

Comment: Some probably useless ideas: have you got the latest VS2010 service pack installed? Are your empty public constructors calling : base() (not sure if that's necessary). Does it happen if you create a brand new blank UserControl?

Comment: You need to look for an exception that get swallowed with a diagnostic.  Start another instance of VS and use Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the first one.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.  Go back to the first instance and start designing.

Comment: And do double-check how your SO user name affects your code.

Comment: The designer file **explicitly warns you** not to do what you've done. And you're surprised it's going wrong?

Comment: @TomW - I said in my question - I am not editing the .designer.cs, the constructor call missing in the file is the symptom of the problem.

Comment: The part where you mention the designer is not clear. I and at least one other poster have assumed that when you say a line is going missing, you expected it to be there because you put it there. I can't edit the comment and the conversation wouldn't make sense if I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the problem... you are putting stuff in the ".designer.cs" code... Don't.  That's Microsoft's sandbox.  When WinForms forms and visual controls are created, they are typically in a "set" such as

```
MyForm.cs   (place for YOUR code)
   MyForm.designer.cs  (Microsoft's sandbox area for designer stuff)
   MyForm.resx   (Resource file -- if used, specific to this form).
```

That said, if you open your WinForm via the normal "Designer", and right-click "view code", it will bring up the MyForm.cs code set.  Notice its a

```
PARTIAL PUBLIC CLASS MyForm : Window
{
   public MyForm()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

The "MyForm.Designer.cs" and "MyForm.cs" basically work as a team.  Your stuff in addition to Microsoft's stuff.  Depending on what you are trying to do, you can hook it in here in THIS constructor for the overall form.  If you need to prepare some data connection, query data, populate lists or whatever that will be used in the form. you can do in many ways (either before or after).

```
   public MyForm()
   {
      DoYourStuff();
      InitializeComponent();
      // or DoYourStuff here after designer controls are all initialized.
   }

   private void DoYourStuff()
   {  put it here }
```

Sometimes you may want to do things after the entire form is loaded, but before final presentation to the user.  Sometimes, I've actually put a hook after the LOADED is complete for the entire form (the form and ALL it's controls).  So I've done something like:

```
public MyForm()
{

   Load += MyAfterInitializeComponents;
   InitializeComponent();
}


private void MyAfterInitializeComponents(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   DoYourStuff(); 
}
```

If there's something specific you are trying to do, maybe some sample code to help integrate within YOUR sandbox of window-based code.

Comment: as I said in my question, I am *not* modifying the .designer.cs file - the designer.cs file was modifying ITSELF to not call the constructor of my custom control which made the control undisplayable.

I'll test out your solution on my code - it turned out the problem I had was an overrriden OnLoad function which had a DoStuff() that caused problems - I thought OnLoad only happened at run time; the solution was to put DoStuff inside if(!DesignMode).  Do functions added to Load only get called for !DesignMode?

Comment: @trycatch... so are you good now?  It was a little unclear from your comment.  I use hooks by += an event handler to do the normal IN ADDITION to the += hook I want to run (per my example).

Comment: I'm currently using if(!DesignMode) to surround my code which was crashing it; this works but feels sloppy.  So I'm definitely going to give your Load += Foo() a try later.  I was using override OnLoad(), and evidently when you do that and open the form in the design view, the OnLoad is called.  I'll have to test if Load+= doesn't execute in DesignMode.

Comment: Okay, I take it back; neither way is completely working.  I have a control acting up again.  I've added a try/catch and I'm trying adding the control to a new dialog - I'm printing out the stack trace and it is ABSOLUTELY stepping into my initialization code whichever way I use.  Using if !DesignMode, it says DesignMode.ToString() is false in my stack trace..  using Load += it also steps into the code.  What in the world is going on??  This function is not referenced anywhere else in the entire project.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, I can view the control in it's Design Mode just fine...?

Comment: Ugh disregard.  Stupid mistake.  I'm beginning to hate custom controls - too easy to totally fubar.  :/